# Where, in the ruleset files, is defined whether a trade route can be established here?

Tags: mods, freeciv

For example, in the "classic" `game.ruleset`, I see

```
[actionenabler_traderoute]
    action = "Establish Trade Route"
    actor_reqs    =
        { "type",   "name", "range", "present"
          "UnitFlag", "TradeRoute", "Local", TRUE
        }
```

which, as far as I understands, tells us that the unit must have the `TradeRoute` flag in `units.ruleset`.

Where do we see that, for example, the destination city must be *"far enough"* or, in the case of the `Augmented2` modpack, *"foreign and not at war"* ?

I would suppose something in effects.ruleset, but I haven't found what.

Answer (score 2):

> Where do we see that, for example, the destination city must be *"far enough"* ...

Under "Start New Game" > "More Game Options...", go to the "Economic" tab, where you can specify the "minimum distance for trade routes":

[image]

Comment: Good catch : I was so focused on the .ruleset files that I forgot to check the UI. Thanks. Original question still open though.

Comment: @ÉricViala What is the "original question"?

Comment: in the title ? ..............................